# How to add a fixed video background without messing up the design

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website design. In the design I am trying to add a video background in the header with `position:fixed`. But for some reason, all the elements below the header just ends on top of the video messing up the design.

This is my code so far

## index.html

```
<div class="first_part">
  <header>
    <div class="test">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="{% static 'videos/hero.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
  </header>

  <h1 class='hero_title'>THIS IS THE HEADER</h1>

</div>

<div class="second_part">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
    irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

</div>
```

## index.css

```
header video {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hero_title {
  color: #F2B705;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -300px;
}

.second_part {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffb347;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffb347, #ffcc33);
}
```

This is the result of the code when the position of the video is set to fixed. The elements in the `div 'second_part'` however should appear below the video.

[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: You can check on codepen, for example you need something like this: https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/GgPLVW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `position: fixed` content gets automatically put on top. If you want to move certain text to another position, you could wrap the fixed element in another element with `position: relative` and style that, since other content won't cover that element.

To read more about different CSS positions, go to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp